# Getting List of objects with max version property from list of objects Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have a list of object. Object contain name and version now in the List we have different names with version and same name with different version.
eg:

```
[
{
"name": "ss",
"version": 1
},
{
"name": "ss",
"version": 2
},
{
"name": "sam",
"version": 1
},
{
"name": "sam",
"version": 2
},
{
"name": "sim",
"version": 1
}
]
```

Now in the response i need something like below

```
[
{
"name": "ss",
"version": 2
},
{
"name": "sam",
"version": 2
},
{
"name": "sim",
"version": 1
}
]
```

Can we do this using java8 features?

Comment: why use java8 features do this?looks cool?But that doesn't give you an idea of ​​how the data behaves when you actually loop through it, it seems, you just need a nice looking answer

Comment: What do you want in your result? Unique objects with the latest version?

Comment: yes Unique Object with latest version

Comment: I'd recommend you try something first using a json parser (Jackson, Gson, javax.json, ...) and a `Map<String, YourObject>` where the key would be the name. Then you just keep the version with the highest version encountered so far for each name in the map. This can be done with earlier Java versions too but if you're looking for Java 8 features have a look at `Map.merge(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

i think two solutions

1. you can use stream to solve the problem.first,group by the name field;then,get the bigger version.
2. you can use the map,when put a object to map,judge the version field.if the version is bigger,you can put it in map.

Comment: First approach worked. Thanks for your ans.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a POJO class like this:

```java
class YourObject {
  private String name;
  private int version;
  // setters & getters
}
```

this should do the trick:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.function.BinaryOperator.maxBy;
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

// ...

List<YourObject> list = ...

// ...

List<YourObject> maxVersions = new ArrayList<>(
       list.stream()
           .collect(toMap(YourObject::getName, identity(),
                          maxBy(comparing(YourObject::getVersion))))
           .values()
);
```